# How to drop duplicates in condition drop_duplicates() does not work at all?

Tags: python, pandas

I am picking names of the same starting letter.

When the result comes out for any rows over 2, it is automatically repeated the part other than the first row and the last row though the bottom statement still reads non-repeated rows. `Drop_duplicates()` does not work at all, the repeated rows can not be deleted.

[image: Pls refer to images I scan as below]

Bonus question: Why is the value selection `Numbers>13908` not working when there's only one matching row?

Comment: You have to improve your English, or while using translator, try to use very short and simple sentences. Your post is not understandable/readable. I have noticed later that you added code and data with an image. It is also preferable to embed all the informations in your question... it should be self consistent

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly,

```
import pandas as pd

namesDf = pd.DataFrame() 
namesDf['Names'] = ['Emily', 'Elizabeth', 'Erin', 'Erica', 'Erin', 'Erica']
namesDf['Numbers'] = [123144, 23423, 13909, 14000, 13909, 14000]
```

DataFrame output:

```
       Names  Numbers
0      Emily   123144
1  Elizabeth    23423
2       Erin    13909
3      Erica    14000
4       Erin    13909
5      Erica    14000
```

Now we remove the duplicates:

```
namesDf = namesDf[namesDf.Numbers > 13908].drop_duplicates('Numbers', keep = 'first')
```

This will keep the first instance and delete other duplicate instances

```
       Names  Numbers
0      Emily   123144
1  Elizabeth    23423
2       Erin    13909
3      Erica    14000
```

To keep the last instance and delete the other instances, change keep to last:

```
namesDf = namesDf[namesDf.Numbers > 13908].drop_duplicates('Numbers', keep = 'last')
```

If you want to remove all instances where duplicates occur then change keep attribute to false:

```
namesDf = namesDf[namesDf.Numbers > 13908].drop_duplicates('Numbers', False)
```

Is this what you expect?

Comment: Yes, exactly your answer is more than I have expected. Thank u so much!

Comment: It does not work. Might it be drop_duplicates() is useless to instances after groupby()?

Comment: The code I have added works for my sample dataset which is very similar to yours. Perhaps you must add the code and sample output and then we can help further.

Comment: Thanks, Trollster! U r so kind. I try to upload the new image.

Comment: I am rookie...I dont know how to add a new image. Maybe I shall draw another question and attach image there...